# Sample code for list/detail Android Activities

Tags: android

My understanding is that best practices for a simple app with list and detail Activities would be a `startActivityForResult()`. Let's say I have an app with `model Product (id, name, price)` and `ProductListActivity` and `ProductDetailActivity`.

I am having a hard time understanding which of the activities would contain `startActivityForResult()` and which would have `setResult()` and what the result would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My understanding is that best practices for a simple app with list and detail >Activities would be a startActivityForResult().

I would not agree with that statement.

In my opinion, the best way would be to set up a [onListItemClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html#onListItemClick(android.widget.ListView, android.view.View, int, long)) in your ProductListActivity.

When an item in the list is clicked, the onListItemClick() method will be called, from the arguments you'll be able to figure out exactly which item in the list was clicked (for example using the second argument - **position**, which is the position of the clicked item in the list, starting from zero).

Once you figure out which item was clicked, you'll create an [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) and put the required extras in there (for example the position of the clicked item).
You'll then use that intent to start your ProductDetailActivity, by calling startActivity().

Then, in your ProductDetailActivity you'll get that intent using getIntent(), extract the extras from that intent and then use them to decide what to display in your activity (for example, display some text associated with a position in your listview from the ProductListActivity). You can get extras from an intent using getExtra*() methods.

You would use startActivityForResult() if you wanted to get some result back from that activity, which in your example doesn't seem to be the case, you simply want to display some details. Now imagine that your activity did some calculations and you wanted to get the final value back, then using startActivityForResult() would be one of the ways of passing that value back.

Comment: thanks for a great explanation! Makes perfect sense. Except, in my case, I would prefer to use the item Id (long id) instead of position. I will accept your answer!

Comment: P.S. I cannot upvote your answer since I have not earned 15+ point reputation

Comment: You are welcome,  glad I could help. Yes, the same logic applies to the id parameter too.